# How is my touchscreen working? Can you tell me?

Tags: touchscreen

I have a dell 15r XPS. Dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10. Touchscreen works awesome in Windows 8. Never worked in Ubuntu and I didn't expect it ever would. One day I happen to touch the screen and I have touch capability in Ubuntu. Not all the time, but most boot ups has me with touch.

What do I need to show you, for you to tell me what is driving my touchscreen? IE what would I install to get it to work next time I need to install?

Comment: I have an acer aspire v5 with touchscreen. Came with windows 8. I formatted the hard drive and only run Ubuntu now and touchscreen works flawless. I keep everything updated and even installed Ubuntu 14.04. Touchscreen still works fine.
Have you installed all recent updates?

Comment: Yep keep it totally updated. It's odd, sometimes the touchscreen works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm just curious on why, and what I could do to force it to work if it's not working. Very little information on the net on touchscreens and ubuntu. I'm glad yours is working for you though, that's awesome!

Comment: So currently it's back to not working. Works fine when booting up to windows. Any ideas on how to check, list or otherwise tell this thing it has a touch screen?